# Can I use @Input and @Output simultaneously In Angular?

Tags: angular

I am using `@Input` to send 'value' and 'type' from the parent component to the child component (this is working fine). Now I am trying to call parent components 'remove' method from the child on a button click using `@Output`.

I have put alert functions in the child and parent component functions. I am only seeing an alert message from the child when I click the button and not the parent. I don't know what I am missing for the child to send an event to the parent.

Child Component:

```html
<div class="btn" (click) = "test()" >
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter-tag',
    templateUrl: './filter-tag.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filter-tag.component.less'],
})
export class FilterTagComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() removeItemEvent = new EventEmitter();
    constructor() { }
    value_: string = '';
    type_: string = ''
    @Input()
    set value(value: string) {
      this.value_ = value;
    }
    @Input()
    set type(value: string) {
      this.type_ = value;
    }
    test() {
        this.removeItemEvent.emit();
        alert('Victor');
    }
}
```

Parent Component:

```html
<app-filter-tag
   [value]="item.name"
   [type]="item.tagType"
   (removeItemEvent)="remove()"
></app-filter-tag>
```

```js
ngOnInit() {}

remove() {
  alert('Hugo');
}
```

Comment: This looks correct as far as I can see. Check your import statements, could it be that you have imported the wrong EventEmitter? It should come from '@angular/core'.

Comment: Good news... I copied your code into [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66541570?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and it works fine.  I wonder if your browser is suppressing multiple alert pop ups...?

Comment: I had made a silly mistake and put <app-filter-tag> in the wrong place(I am new to angular). I figured it out from the StackBlitz code you created, Thanks a lot!!.